# How to use Pug/Jade iterations to create multiple elements with different content?

Tags: pug, pugjs, jade4j

I'm presently learning iterations in Pug/Jade. I'd like to use this tool going forward.

In the code below, you basically have what's supposed to amount to a slider.

In the first instance, the `#{i}` is supposed to return values 1-4 to each listed class, but instead compiles just the same. Though I've seen this technique work for others.

Secondly, with regard to my `data` array, I've been able to get the `title` value to show in each `section`, however, getting the `button` value to appear within the same container seems to be the challenge.

```
- var data=[{'title':'Home Run', 'button':'It\'s a win'}, {'title':'Testing', 'button':'Tested'}, {'title':'Foreground', 'button':'Background'}, {'title':'Forest', 'button':'Trees'}]


.slide-container
  - var i=0;
    while (i++ < 4)
      mixin list(title)
        section(class='slide-#{i}')
            h2= title


  each item in data
    +list(item.title)
    a(href='#')= item.button
```

The code above returns the following:

```
<div class="slide-container">
    <section class="slide-#{i}">
      <h2>Home Run</h2>
    </section><a href="#">It's a win</a>
    <section class="slide-#{i}">
      <h2>Testing</h2>
    </section><a href="#">Tested</a>
    <section class="slide-#{i}">
      <h2>Foreground</h2>
    </section><a href="#">Background</a>
    <section class="slide-#{i}">
      <h2>Forest</h2>
    </section><a href="#">Trees</a>
</div>
```

Which is great, but not what I need. What I would really like to see compiled is the following:

```
<div class="slide-container">
    <section class="slide-1">
      <h2>Home Run</h2>
      <a href="#">It's a win</a>
    </section>
    <section class="slide-2">
      <h2>Testing</h2>
      <a href="#">Tested</a>
    </section>
    <section class="slide-3">
      <h2>Foreground</h2>
      <a href="#">Background</a>
    </section>
    <section class="slide-4">
      <h2>Forest</h2>
      <a href="#">Trees</a>
    </section>
</div>
```

The pen can be viewed here: https://codepen.io/jobaelish/pen/jYyGQM?editors=1000

What must I do with my code to get the desired result?

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok. So, a new bit of code. I was able to solve some of the issues I initially had, resolving the class iteration by using `+ i` instead of `#{i}`.

Secondly, by adding a `block` tag to my Pug mixin, I was able to include the links, no prob.

Here's the new code:

```
- var data=[{'title':'Home Run', 'button':'It\'s a win'}, {'title':'Testing', 'button':'Tested'}, {'title':'Foreground', 'button':'Background'}, {'title':'Forest', 'button':'Trees'}]


mixin list(title)
  h2= title
  block

.slide-container
  each item in data
    //- - var i = 0;
    //-   while i < 4
    section(class='slide-' + i++)
      +list(item.title)
        a(href='#')= item.button
```

Which renders:

```
<div class="slide-container">
  <section class="slide-NaN">
    <h2>Home Run</h2><a href="#">It's a win</a>
  </section>
  <section class="slide-NaN">
    <h2>Testing</h2><a href="#">Tested</a>
  </section>
  <section class="slide-NaN">
    <h2>Foreground</h2><a href="#">Background</a>
  </section>
  <section class="slide-NaN">
    <h2>Forest</h2><a href="#">Trees</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

So, the only thing left is to get the classes to iterate properly when compiled. I've gotten some result of either `style-0`, `style-5`, and now `style-NaN`.

How can I now get this to work as `style-1`, `style-2`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: Attribute interpolation (expressions such as `class='slide-#{i}'`) is [not supported anymore](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) in Pug. Try doing `class='slide-' + i`, instead.

On the second question: You have two separate loops, which is why the buttons and headings are separate. If you want them to appear in the same `section` containers, you need to somehow put both in one loop, so that one iteration adds both.

On your third question: I'm not entirely sure I understood the question, but this is a [pen](https://codepen.io/pen/) with how I would fix it:

```
.slide-container
  each item, i in data
    section(class='slide-' + (i + 1))
      +list(item.title)
        a(href='#')= item.button
```

Comment: The first part I figured out a little after this with some more research.

The second part I was able to solve by adding `block`. However, I can't seem to get the `section` to repeat without repeating the data variable.

I'll update the question with the new code.

Comment: See my edited question for an answer to your last question.

Comment: The updated code worked like a charm! I can't tell you how much I appreciate it. I can now use this in my future code... thanks again.